# Launch a .desktop file from boot

Tags: 14.04, startup, cron, .desktop

I have a `.desktop` file on my desktop that launches a html page. I need the `.desktop` file to run from startup, what would be the best way to do this?

I have tried `crontab` and also the *startup application* but have been unsuccessful so far.

```
[Desktop Entry] Version=1.0 
Name=Chromium Web Browser 
GenericName=Web Browser 
GenericName[en_GB]=Web Browser 
Comment=Access the Internet 
Comment[en_GB]=Access the Internet 
Exec=chromium-browser --kiosk file:///home/user1/Desktop/mltest/vms.html 
Terminal=false X-MultipleArgs=false 
Type=Application 
Icon=chromium-browser 
Categories=Network;WebBrowser;
MimeType=text/html;text/xml;application/xhtml_xml;x-scheme-handler/http;x-scheme‌​-handler/https; 
StartupWMClass=Chromium-browser 
StartupNotify=true 
Actions=NewWindow;Incognito;TempProfile; 
X-AppInstall-Package=chromium-browser
```

Comment: Post the content of that .desktop file.

Comment: [Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Chromium Web Browser
GenericName=Web Browser
GenericName[en_GB]=Web Browser
Comment=Access the Internet
Comment[en_GB]=Access the Internet
Exec=chromium-browser --kiosk file:///home/user1/Desktop/mltest/vms.html
Terminal=false
X-MultipleArgs=false
Type=Application
Icon=chromium-browser
Categories=Network;WebBrowser;
MimeType=text/html;text/xml;application/xhtml_xml;x-scheme-handler/http;x-scheme-handler/https;
StartupWMClass=Chromium-browser
StartupNotify=true
Actions=NewWindow;Incognito;TempProfile;
X-AppInstall-Package=chromium-browser

Comment: Name[en_GB]=chrome

[Desktop Action NewWindow]
Name=Open a New Window
Exec=chromium-browser

[Desktop Action Incognito]
Name=Open a New Window in incognito mode
Exec=chromium-browser --incognito
[Desktop Action TempProfile]
Name=Open a New Window with a temporary profile
Exec=chromium-browser --temp-profile

Comment: I added a solution for firefox, same thing for chromium, just change the command.

Comment: Related [Autostarting .desktop application at startup not working](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/256929/autostarting-desktop-application-at-startup-not-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in need of launching a web page via browser then add to startup applications something like this:

`/usr/bin/firefox /path/to/html/file.html`

or

`/usr/bin/firefox http://some-site.com/`

No need to run .desktop file.

EDIT: So in your case `chromium-browser --kiosk file:///home/user1/Desktop/mltest/vms.html`

Comment: the .desktop launches a local html file in chrome kiosk mode, could I adapt your code for that

Comment: Sure, this is the needed line `chromium-browser --kiosk file:///home/user1/Desktop/mltest/vms.html`

Comment: "No need to run .desktop file". Actually Startup Applications *creates* a `.desktop` file with your command in `~/.config/autostart`.

Comment: It sure does but it's not quite the same content.