# Run .desktop file at startup (and follow its Icon= specification)

Tags: launcher, icons, startup, .desktop, plank

I want to run a script at startup that would use [a custom icon that should appear in Plank dock](https://askubuntu.com/q/882888/47206).

For that I have created a `.desktop` file in `~/.local/share/applications` that runs the script (see all the details in the question linked above) and that also contains the line `Icon=` that specifies the custom icon I want.

**If I execute the desktop file with double-click the `Icon=` line is not followed and the custom icon is not used in Plank.**

The `.desktop` file does its job if I execute it from an application launcher or with the command `gtk-launch <.desktop>` (as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/664272/47206)).

But I want its effects to be triggered automatically **at startup**: I want the script set under `Exec=` line to be run but also I want the icon set under the `Icon=` line to be shown in the dock.

If I simply add the path to the desktop file to the startup list, it doesn't do anything at startup: the script is not run at all.

If I add to startup list the command  `gtk-launch <.desktop>` the script is run but the icon is not used.

Comment: Related: [Launch a .desktop file from boot](https://askubuntu.com/q/541462/13330)

Comment: Related [Autostarting .desktop application at startup not working](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/256929/autostarting-desktop-application-at-startup-not-working)